# Python Pandas Groupby Dropping DateTime Columns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, nat

I am having some trouble using groupby.median() and groupby.mean() on a DataFrame containing intermittent NaT values. Specifically, I have several columns in a dataset calculating various time differences based on other columns. In some instances, no time difference exists, causing a NaT value similar to the example below:

```
Group    Category    Start Time      End Time      Time Diff
  A         1        08:00:00.000    08:00:00.500      .500
  B         1        09:00:00.000    09:02:00.000  2:00.000
  B         1        09:00:00.000      NaT           NaT
  A         2        09:00:00.000    09:02:00.000  2:00.000
  A         2        09:00:00.000    09:01:00.000  1:00.000
  A         2        08:00:00.000    08:00:01.500     1.500
```

Any time I run `df.groupby(['Group', 'Category'].median()` or `.mean()` any column that contains NaT is dropped from the result set. I've attempted a `fillna` but NaT's seemed to remain. As an added point of context, this script worked correctly in an older version of Anaconda Python (1.x). I was recently able to upgrade my work computer to 2.0.1 at which point this issue began creeping up.

EDIT: I will leave my thoughts about NaT's up above in the event that they are a factor, but upon further review it seems that my problem actually lies in the fact that these columns are timedelta64s. Does anyone know of any workarounds to obtain mean/median on timedeltas?

Thanks very much for any insight you may have!

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: @joris I have pandas 0.14.0. I did come up with a workaround - see my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further googling/experimentation I confirmed that the issue appeared to be related to columns which were `timedelta64`. In order to perform `pd.groupby` on these columns I first converted them to floats like so:

`df['End Time'] = df['End Time'].astype('timedelta64[ms]') / 86400000`

There may be a more elegant solution to this but this allowed me to move forward with my analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a current limitation of pandas, there is an issue to fix this (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6884), hopefully it will get in version 0.15

Comment: @joris Great, thanks for passing along the link. I will keep an eye on this issue. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up here,  this bug seems to have been fixed somewhere between Pandas version 1.3.4 and version 2.2.0  (two versions I had convenient to test), but I'm not sure when or how, and it's not mentioned in the PR above.

So, if possible, update your Pandas and it should fix it.

If someone knows, can they put when the fix happened here for the future?